# Need to set root and prefix values everytime when I boot to ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2

I'm having windows 10 and ubuntu 18.04 dual booted, when I try to boot to ubuntu then it directly opens windows 10, to overcome this I opened boot menu using F12 and then selected ubuntu from boot menu but still after selecting ubuntu it boots windows

To get into ubuntu I need a bootable USB each time and then from grub rescue I need to set root and prefix values each time, I also tried updating grub and another things mentioned in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/867519/grub-rescue-setting-boot-and-prefix-again-and-again),
Can anyone suggest a solution for this so that I can get into Ubuntu easily without bootable USB.

PC details : Acer Nitro 5, EFI mode, GPT partition

Edit : I tried the suggested steps but issue is still unsolved

Comment: You will need to reinstall grub so the linux bootloader ends up on your system disk instead of on the USB.

Comment: Check https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Please boot into Windows, then click on he Windows START icon at bottom left. Hold down {SHIFT} and while holding it down, choose Shut Down. Then, power back up; are you able to choose Ubuntu and boot into Ubuntu? Please advise by clicking [edit] and tell us what happened.

Comment: @vanadium I tried reinstalling grub, but it didn't solve the issue.
I can access to ubuntu and then I followed the steps you suggested to check and ran these commands ```sudo update-grub``` and then ```sudo grub-install /dev/sda```  but still the issue persists :|

Comment: @K7AAY I tried the steps you suggested but that is not working and still it directly opens Windows and also when I select ubuntu from boot menu then still it opens Windows